# Problem with adds animation after the element has appeared

Tags: javascript, css, frontend

I have 3 buttons and have photo - after  im press the button  i should see photo(if i click button lovers i see lovers photo etc).My code:

```
  const headerbtn = document.querySelector(".portfolio-menu");
  const headerPhoto = document.querySelector(".portfolio-wrapper");
  const allPhoto = headerPhoto.querySelectorAll(".all");
  
  const changePhoto = (name) => {
    let elem = headerPhoto.querySelectorAll(name);

    allPhoto.forEach((x) => {
      x.classList.add("hidden");

      x.classList.remove("animated", "fadeIn");
    });
    no.style.display = "none";
    allBtn.forEach((x) => {
      x.classList.remove("active");
    });
    elem.forEach((x) => {
      x.classList.remove("hidden");

      x.classList.add("animated", "fadeIn");
    });
  };
  function changeAll() {
    allPhoto.forEach((x) => {
      x.classList.add("hidden");
      x.classList.remove("animated", "fadeIn")
    });
    allPhoto.forEach((x) => {
      x.classList.add("animated", "fadeIn");
      x.classList.remove("hidden");
    })}
  headerbtn.querySelector(".all").addEventListener("click", changeAll);
  headerbtn.querySelector(".lovers").addEventListener("click", () => {
    changePhoto(".lovers");
  });
  headerbtn.querySelector(".chef").addEventListener("click", () => {
    changePhoto(".chef");
  });
}});
```

The hidden class has the value `display=block`. So, I press the button with the class "lovers" and I see only photos of lovers, and they appear with animation, after that I press the button with the class "all", I see all the photos, but not all photos have animation (photo "lovers ' don't have an animation but all the others do, but I added a class animation to `changeAll()` and the console log shows it to me, but still no animation). After that, I press the "lovers" button again - and I see a photo of lovers, but they also do not have animation.

Comment: The settings in the first foreach of your changeAll function achieve nothing as the settings are immediately overwritten by the next foreach - before the system  has been given a chance to implement the changes.

Comment: @AHaworth  if i use setTimeout will it help?

Comment: Probably, yes, gives the system time to repaint things. Otherwise, once an animation is set it won't do it again because it thinks it's already done it.

Comment: @AHaworth still dont work.but if i add another class animation for all photo its all works, of course we have different animation in photos - but anyway its works. Hmm, 
so problem in deleting or adding animation class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either requestAnimationFrame or a setTimeout to make sure that there's a tick in between the time that the class is removed and the time that it's re-added.

Run the snippet and click the Show All button multiple times:

```js
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll("img");

function changeAll() {
  imgs.forEach((x, i) => {
    x.classList.remove("animated", "fadeIn");
    x.removeAttribute("style");
    x.style.animationDelay = `${i * 0.25}s`;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      x.classList.add("animated", "fadeIn");
    });
  });
}
```

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  padding-block: 1rem;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  margin: auto;
  width: max-content;
}

img {
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0;
}

.animated {
  animation-duration: 0.25s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.fadeIn {
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    scale: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    scale: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <button onclick="changeAll()">Show All</button>
</header>
<main>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/600/900" alt="dog" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/0/600" alt="laptop" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/63/700/600" alt="coffee" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/70/900" alt="trees" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/112/800/500" alt="wheat" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/168/200/300" alt="rocks" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/400/800/400" alt="shrub" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/216/500/800" alt="path" />
</main>
```

Comment: nice. I read about another method, it call  transitionend. we just need listen this event

Comment: Yup, just be aware that there are two different events: transitionend and animationend.  Also, you'll need to handle when an animation has not ended before the user clicks on one of the buttons.

Comment: but setTimeout really helped in my situation. Thanks for the info)